# How to search for a string and append it to its previous line in gvim?

Tags: linux, vim

Below is a snippet,

```
a.b.c    
not found
```

I want "not found" to be appended to a.b.c, please let me know how to do it using gvim.

Thanks & Regards,

RMK

Answer (score 4):

> search for a string and append it to its previous line

```
:g/not found/-j
```

- `g` global search
- `not found` string
- `-` previous line
- `j` join (append)

Comment: Wouldn't it be: `:g/not found/-1 normal! J` ?

Comment: Sure, if you want to write it more complicated than necessary (by not using the Ex command `j`). ;-)